# How do I remove auto complete from <input>?

Tags: html, input

How do I remove that input preview and the white border? There are my old inputs and I would like to remove them.

[image: auto complete]

Comment: This is something you can turn on and off in your browser settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `<input autocomplete="off">`, see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion).